# Is it possible to read Doc Strings of a Python file w/o using python shell?

Tags: python-3.6

I was wondering if there is any way we can read doc strings present in a python file from command line, prior to importing it, or w/o using any Ipython or Python kernel, just like 'man' command does.

Comment: Since Python comes with this functionality built-in, **why** would you want to use another tool for this?  Any other tool would be duplicating this functionality & so why would it be worthwhile installing another tool vs just using Python?

Comment: But Python requires you to manually import file, then only we can read it. If there is any work around which does not require you to fire python shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [execute some python code from the command line](https://docs.python.org/3.6/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-c), so given a module named `my_module.py`, and a function named `my_function`, the following:

```
python -c "from my_module import my_function;print my_function.__doc__"
```

will print out the docstring